# In Salesforce Apex how do I serve up a binary file

Tags: web-services, salesforce, apex-code

I have a VF page that is basically a view into our CMS system.  It logs in with a generic ID and with web services is able to get and display a list of files.  Now I would like to be able to click on a file and have it opened in a new window.  I have a CMS web service that returns a byte stream of the file.  How do I set an Apex Remote Action to return that stream to the browser?  And furthermore how do I open this in a new tab?

I'd like a remove action like:

```
public static HttpResponse sendRequest(String endpoint, String method)
{
    HttpRequest req = new HttpRequest();
    req.setMethod(method);
    req.setEndpoint(endpoint);

    HttpResponse resp;
    if (Test.isRunningTest())
    {
        resp = new HttpResponse();
        resp.setBody('');
    }
    else
    {
        Http http = new Http();
        resp = http.send(req);
    }

    return resp;
}


@RemoteAction
public static HttpResponse open(docid)
{
    return sendRequest(API_DOMAIN + '/ws/open/' + docid + '/', 'GET');
}
```

And then on the UI side:

```
MainBehavior.Open= function(docid) {
    Visualforce.remoting.Manager.invokeAction(
        '{!$RemoteAction.ResourceCenterController.open}',
                    docid,
        function(result, event)
        {
            if (event.status)
            {
                 return result;
            } 
            else if (event.type === 'exception') 
            {
                alert('Not able to open!\n\n' + event.message);
            }
            else
            {
                alert('Not able to open!');
            }
        }
    );
```

And later on with a click event:

```
window.open(MainBehavior.Open(docid), '_blank');
```

I know this code doesn't work as is, but this is my goal.  Any suggestions on how to go about this?

Answer (score -1):

```
if (event.status) {
 // window.open(result,'_blank'); //file in new window
 window.location.href =result;    //file in same window
}
```

This line will open file. Avoid opening in new window. AdBlockers will block new window opened through JS in most of the browsers.